# Чем заменить стрелочные функции в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, события

В сообществе React многие считают использование стрелочных функций плохой идеей, ибо они каждый раз будут ререндериться, но как от них избавиться, если стрелочные функции принимают event с onChange? или, допустим, я в цикле создаю для каждого условного товара onClick добавить в корзину и onClick должен вызвать функцию,передав id

Comment: все зависит от способа использования. Не стрелочные функции тоже могут приводить к перерендеру

Comment: Вы никак не ответили на мой вопрос

Comment: поэтому это и комментарий, а не ответ. В любом случае без конкретного примера кода, в котором ты хочешь заметить одно на другое нельзя корректно ответить.

Comment: Вы что-то не то прочитали. В React при перерендере компонента и стрелочная фнукция, и именованая будут одинаково выполняться заново. Так что вопрос изначально имеет сомнительное утверждение.

Comment: Выполнятся то занова будет - это понятно, cмысл в том, что она будет заново создаваться, если она стрелочная

Comment: @Nikita ссылку приведите на документацию. Так как и нестрелочная тоже будет заново создаваться.

Comment: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В той статье, которую вы привели https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render
Дальше есть решение вашей проблемы:
https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#example-passing-params-using-data-attributes

> В качестве альтернативного подхода вы можете использовать DOM API,
>   чтобы хранить необходимые для обработчиков событий данные. Рассмотрите
>   этот подход, если вам нужно оптимизировать большое количество
>   элементов или использовать дерево визуализации, полагающееся на
>   компонент React.PureComponent для проверки на равенство.

```
const A = 65 // ASCII-код символа

class Alphabet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      justClicked: null,
      letters: Array.from({length: 26}, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(A + i))
    };
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({
      justClicked: e.target.dataset.letter
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Just clicked: {this.state.justClicked}
        <ul>
          {this.state.letters.map(letter =>
            <li key={letter} data-letter={letter} onClick={this.handleClick}> // <--
              {letter}
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```